# Any research on segmentation of non-text contents out of (mostly) text-documents?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

Documents, especially technical ones often contain non-text content in blocks (code snippets, os commands etc). Is there any efficient way to identify the starting and ending lines of those blocks?

Comment: Have you seen LSTM models trained for recognizing punctuation marks?

Answer (score 1):

Although I didn't implement it so far, I am pretty sure natural language text vs code snippets is easy:

For each block, you make compare the distribution of characters to ground-truth natural language text vs. code. See my paper [The WiLI benchmark dataset for written language identification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07779.pdf), page 4 "Single-Character Frequency Analysis".